# Can a Custom ROM affect the performance of my battery?

Tags: custom-roms, battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung

My Device is Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500. 
A week ago, I flashed a custom ROM on my Device, now my phone's battery drains out even if the phone is on stand by. Previously, it degraded but not so drastically. Sometimes the battery percentage increases automatically.

Is it a battery problem or Is it due to the Custom ROM?

Answer (score 1):

It's the custom ROM but it may not be the ROM itself. Most of the times it is the kernel that comes with the ROM that is most influential. But, it is possible that the ROM has a feature or two that is draining the battery.

Also, since it is an S4 I have to ask, is it a Samsung ROM or AOSP? Because AOSP is so much different that usually because it is not the most compatible with the hardware it will take a toll on the battery. Samsung knows how to customize it's software the best so generally Samsung ROMs (doesn't have to be stock) are better than AOSP ROMs on Samsung phones or any OEM phones for that matter.

Comment: It's Samsung's [Ozcan](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/GalaxyS4/GT-i9500/roms/Ozcan/GT-I9500XXUGNH4_OzcanRom_Aroma_v5.1.zip) ROM.

Comment: But how can battery increase itself? 
I keep checking through battery percentage.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that. Did it happen only in this custom ROM or in your previous ROM (stock?)? If it happens only on this custom ROM then it's definitely the reason.

Comment: Happened in stock ROM too, but not in that great extent as compared to Custom ROM. Actually my friend said me that's it battery fault so I'm confused.

Comment: One good thing about Galaxy phones is that they have removable battery. Put a different battery in your phone (from a friend or just buy a different one) and see if it keeps happening. If you are reluctant to buy a second battery just remember that it's good to have a second one, for backup or just because battery life tends to decrease after some time (1-1.5 years). By the way, I recommend Anker's 2600mAh battery (I bought an Anker battery when I had my S1 and it was better than the original).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try replacing battery, and will let u know.

Comment: Good luck and I hope it works :)